# Can I use perl's Parse::RecDescent to parse a file in-place?

Tags: css, parsing, grammar, in-place

I want to write a simple CSS "preprocessor" that comments out constructs in CSS files based on a user input configuration file. The goal is to automate actions such as, "comment all ABC properties that apply to XYZ elements".

Aside from the added comments, the processed CSS files must **otherwise remain identical to the input files** -- including indentation, linefeeds, and original comments.

There are some perl CSS parsers:

https://metacpan.org/pod/CSS (heavy and lite)

https://metacpan.org/pod/CSS::Simple

but they don't preserve structure and/or comments.

I thought about writing my own Parse::RecDescent parser (and there is lots of code in CSS::Parse::Heavy to reference!) but the part I can't figure out is how to preserve the existing text during the parse. I was hoping to return strings of actual content up through the patterns, but Parse::RecDescent seems to discard things like whitespace and linefeeds, and it returns references of bits and pieces of content instead.

Is there a way to get Parse::RecDescent to preserve the *actual* string content, including whitespace and linefeeds (and comments??), up through the productions?

I don't have any code to share because I haven't a single idea get off the ground yet. :(  But here's some example CSS I'd need to parse:

```
/* ====================================
 * <prelreqs>
 */
*[class~="taskreq-d/prelreqs"] > * {
  margin-left: 2em;  // TO-DO - check
}

*[scale="90"]  {        font-size: 90%; }
*[scale="100"] {        font-size: 100%; }
*[scale="110"] {        font-size: 110%; }

@media print{
  /* page style stuff */
  :root{
      /* White page */
      border: 1px solid #c6c6c6;
      background-color:white;
}}
@page table-of-contents {
      @top-left      { content: none; }
      @top-center    { content: none; }
}
@page table-of-contents:left {
      @top-left {
          content: string(toc-header) " | " counter(page, lower-roman);
      }
}
```